# MySql How to get hourly average count

Tags: mysql

I have been looking at several different questions related to hourly average queries but I could not find any that addresses the following.

I have a log table that keeps track on how many times a page is accessed by a user:

```
ID   USERID   PAGEID  SECNO    DATE

1    123      120     14      6/08/2013 10:07:29 AM
1    124      438     1       6/08/2013 11:00:01 AM
1    123      211     18      6/09/2013 14:07:59 PM
1    123      120     14      6/10/2013 05:07:18 PM
1    124      312     4       6/10/2013 08:04:32 PM
1    128      81      54      6/11/2013 07:02:15 AM
```

and I am trying to get two different queries. One that looks like this:

```
HOURLY      Count     Average   

12am        0        0
1am         0        0
2am         0        0
3am         0        0
4am         0        0
5am         1        0
6am         0        0
7am         1        0
8am         0        0
9am         0        0
10am        1        0
11am        1        0
12pm        0        0
1pm         0        0
2pm         1        0
3pm         0        0
4pm         0        0
5pm         1        0
6pm         0        0
7pm         0        0
8pm         1        0
9pm         0        0
10pm        0        0
11pm        0        0
```

The second query like this:

```
DAY      PERCENTAGE

Monday   10%
Tuesday   16%
Wednesday   14%
Thursday   22%
Friday   21%
Saturday   14%
Sunday   3%
```

**Please notice that the average value is just a sample

So far for the first query I have something like this:

```
SELECT 
   HOUR(date) AS hourly, 
   Count(*)  
FROM 
   logs
GROUP BY 
   hourly
```

I tried adding AVG(*) after Count(*) but did not work.

My log table does not have data for every single hour but i still need to display all the hours on my report. if hour empty, then value 0. Any ideas how could I achieve that?

Comment: what is the point of avg? i mean for what field you what to calculate the avg?

Comment: the log sample is just a sample copy of a huge table. i need to know the hourly average that a user accesses a page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this for the first query:

```
SELECT
    h.hour,
    IFNULL(tmp.the_count,0),
    IFNULL(tmp.the_avg,0)
FROM 
    hourly h
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        hourly,
        SUM(visits) the_count,
        SUM(visits)/COUNT(DISTINCT userid) as the_avg
    FROM (
        SELECT 
           HOUR(date) AS hourly, 
           COUNT(*) as visits,
           userid
        FROM 
           logs
        GROUP BY 
           hourly,
           userid
    ) as tmp
    GROUP BY
        hourly
) as tmp
    ON tmp.hourly = h.hour
```

Try this for the second query:

```
SELECT
    theday,
    IFNULL(percentage,0) as percentage
FROM (
    SELECT  DATE_FORMAT('2013-06-16','%W') as theday UNION
    SELECT  DATE_FORMAT('2013-06-16' - INTERVAL 1 DAY,'%W') as theday UNION
    SELECT  DATE_FORMAT('2013-06-16' - INTERVAL 2 DAY,'%W') as theday UNION
    SELECT  DATE_FORMAT('2013-06-16' - INTERVAL 3 DAY,'%W') as theday UNION
    SELECT  DATE_FORMAT('2013-06-16' - INTERVAL 4 DAY,'%W') as theday UNION
    SELECT  DATE_FORMAT('2013-06-16' - INTERVAL 5 DAY,'%W') as theday UNION
    SELECT  DATE_FORMAT('2013-06-16' - INTERVAL 6 DAY,'%W') as theday 
) as weekt
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        DATE_FORMAT(date,'%W') AS daily, 
        (COUNT(*)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM logs))/100 as percentage
    FROM 
        logs 
    WHERE 
        date >= '2013-06-10'
        AND date <= '2013-06-16'
    GROUP BY 
        daily
) as logdata
    ON logdata.daily = weekt.theday
```

Comment: hi Stephan, thanks a lot for the second query works fine, i just however need to be able to show data for the whole week (7 days) despise not having any data in any given day of the week. I know I need to include a left join somewhere here, do I need to create a day of the week table and then do a left join with it or is there another way, do you know?

Comment: i've updated the query, it will show you the results for the current week

Comment: thanks so much for helping me out, still shows only the days i have data. For example, if I select from '2013-06-01' to '2013-06-07' and I do not have any data on '2013-06-04', I still should be able to see that day on the result.

Comment: aaa you want to show for all days even thought you don't have data, got it now, i'll update

Comment: For the hours see my example. For dates you can work with the numbers-table of you can store a calendar-table with dates and additional info, like a customized weekday name or some bank holidays like easter and the like.

Comment: @flaschenpost yeah you are right but you can also generate them on the fly

Comment: @carol1287 pls try the second query because now it should be ok

Comment: For the second query PERFECT, you are a star Stephan thank you so much, it works perfect

Comment: glad i could help :) and the first query?

Comment: for the first query, I need the remaining hours of the day. I just created an hourly table but when i join that I get the same results. Example: left join hourly as h on hour(h.hour) = tmp.hourly

Comment: the first table should be `hourly` and the `LEFT JOIN` my query

Comment: how can i reverse the left join if I have all the select columns I need on the first one?

Comment: thanks Stephan, I was pulling my hair out trying to get the query. I have used your latest sample. I do get all hours now which is perfect, the only problem is the counting. I do not get the count for all hours and I think my problem is basically the way I have inserted the value in the hourly table. In the hourly table I have 24 records (time datatype) starting at 00:00:00 and ending at 23:00:00 - should i do something like this: DATE_FORMAT(tmp.hourly,'%p') = DATE_FORMAT(h.hour,'%p')? After this everything else works perfect.

Comment: i assumed that the `hour` column in `hourly` table was a number, in this case you just need `ON tmp.hourly = HOUR(h.hour)`

Comment: As I said, YOU ARE A BLESSED STAR :)

Answer (score 2):

SQL has no way to "create" an hour out of nothing. So the simple trick is to have a table `numbers (number int)` with the numbers you need (may be 1- 31 to be ready for month, or 1-366 for year). That table you can left join with your data in the kind of

```
select n.number as hour, count(*) as cnt 
from numbers as n
left join logtable as l
on hour(l.date) = n.number
group by n.number
```

You could "simulate" it without a table, but there are several occasions where that table is helpful.

Comment: Hi Flashenpost, thanks a lot for your suggestion. I have created a hourly table from 00:00 to 23:00 and I will attempt now to left join that with Stephan's first query and see if that works